# Fetch value from item.response

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting value from Firestore using below code, I need to fetch the value of `complaint_date_show`, see attached image for reference. I tried using this code
`console.log(item.payload["complaint_date_show"]); // doesn't work`
But it says **undefined**.

How can I get this value?

```
    this.firestore.collection('complaints' , ref => ref 
.limit(5)
).snapshotChanges()
.subscribe(response => {
if(!response.length){
  console.log("no data available");
  return false;
}
this.firstInResponse = response[0].payload.doc;
this.lastInResponse = response[response.length - 1].payload.doc;

this.tableData = [];
for(let item of response){
  console.log(item.payload["complaint_date_show"]); // doesn't work
  this.tableData.push(item.payload.doc.data());
```

[image]

Comment: If `response` is an array of results then we should get `item["complaint_datae_show"]`. I can not see `payload` in response.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to call the data function first. Try:

```
console.log(item.payload.doc.data()["complaint_date_show"]);
```

For readability purposes, I'd recommend to store it in a variable and then access it, like this:

```
const product = item.payload.doc.data();
console.log(product.complaint_date_show)
```

Comment: `item.payload.doc.data()["complaint_date_show"]`  this solution works, other didnt

Comment: There was a typo in the code, I fixed it now. Anyways the other solution should work as well, it's simply making this more readable by assigning the data to a variable, no functionality difference there.  Feel free to mark as solved + up-vote if it's solved, cheers :)

Comment: 2nd option still has error - `Property 'complaint_date_show' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

Comment: This is a Typescript error. You need to add an interface to it or use it like this:

const product: any = item.payload.doc.data()

I highly recommend to use an interface and map the response you get from the server.